# How to install drivers when changing operating system from Linux to Windows 7

Tags: drivers, operating-systems, multi-boot

I have bought new hp pro book 4530s which came with Linux OS, now if I want to remove that I have learned that by installing windows drivers wont work? Will it be that way and if so how can I install windows 7

Comment: What have you researched about the laptop, drivers or installing Windows? What have you tried doing?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install drivers to install Windows (except in cases where you're using a RAID disk controller, which the vast majority of laptops don't use). All you have to do is put the Windows DVD into the drive and reboot, booting off the DVD, and following Windows' setup installation wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Install Windows from a CD (erase the Linux partition if you want) and then install the drivers from [HP's web page](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?lang=en&cc=br&prodNameId=5060882&prodSeriesId=5060880&prodTypeId=321957&taskId=135&swLang=8).